# Extract typescript types from function to Object

Tags: typescript

Trying to generate types from given functions types. I would like to get the return type directly from the function and map to the key of the object shown below. There is `ReturnType` I tried but it was not accepting the `reducers` structure.

```
type A = { a: string } 
type B = {  b: string }
type Reducers = {
  aA: (a) => A,
  bB:(b) => B,
}

const reducers: Reducers = {
  aA: (a) => { a },
  bB: (b) => {b },
}
```

how to get the store state like

```
namespace Store {  // I will provide this
  type Project = { // here is where I need to generated types based on reducer function like`type Project = ....`
     aA: A,
     bB: B,
  } 
}
```

Comment: Where is _"the object shown below"_?

Comment: @Paleo sorry missed it. Just added now, see if it make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure of what you want but here is how to use `ReturnType` in a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type Project = {
  [K in keyof Reducers]: ReturnType<Reducers[K]>
}
```

… Or a more generic version:

```
interface ReducerDict {
  [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => any
}

type Project<T extends ReducerDict> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[K]>
}
```

Comment: This seems to working but, i need more generic. Can i do `type Project<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[K]>
};
`

Comment: @user1595858 I edited. Yes you can but `T` must be limited to a dictionary of functions.